# Why session on IIS is drop quickly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, asp-classic

My project run on IIS7. I have a session state problem: session drops quickly (one minute or less). When I run project on Visual Studio 2010 (local IIS on my computer) I haven't problems with session. How fix this problem on IIS Server?

Comment: IIS closes sessions after unhandled exceptions. Check the IIS log. Provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you have InProc session state and your worker process crashes fatally due to an unhandled thread or task exception, or due to a stack overflow.

Switch to StateServer mode and/or fix the cash.

Comment: Add in web.config: <sessionState mode="StateServer"
      stateConnectionString="tcpip=SampleStateServer:42424"
      cookieless="false"
      timeout="20"/> like this???

Comment: Looks about right. Also look into the error log to look for crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be unhandled exceptions in the application, but it could also be that the clock of the server is set to a different time than yours. That would mean session cookies expire immediately (or at least very quickly) and thus you lose your session.

Comment: I am probably misunderstanding you, but if I read this right and I turn my clock back a year, than I have a SessionState that would last for a year?

Comment: Not entirely, because the ASP.NET session state mechanism would expire the session cookie. But if there is, say, a difference of 1 hour or say 50 minutes between the server and the client, and the server says that the session expires at a given time, then the client could determine that that time has already passed and it then immediately expires the cookie. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that, not what I expected though.